# На странице поиска не переведён таб и текст по результатам поиска

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, список-вопросов-участника

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=test

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если искать по тегу, то не переведённый текст: Results tagged with.

Если в общем, то не переведённый текст: Results found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Relevance: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11351. Предложил вариант:

   > Подходящие
2. Results tagged with: https://ru.traducir.win/string/5819. Предложил:

   > Результаты поиска по метке $tags$
3. Results found: https://ru.traducir.win/string/288. Предложил:

   > Найдено результатов